# Do i have to create nested loops or can i do it with the try function?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me why is asks for an input the second time someone enters an operator and a number?

It is an calculator and i want to except the Valueerror the sedcond time but the code always repeats twice and doenst exit the try function.

Can someone please help me in the right direction?

```
import locale

## Defining the calculator functions
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2


def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

## Asking for the first user input
while number_2 = None :

    try:
        operation, number_2 = input('''
    Starting at zero
    Please enter an operator and a number 
    Enter: ''').split()
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print('Please put a space between the operator and the number!')
    else:
        break

##Making the input calculatable
number_1 = float(0)
number_2 = float(number_2)

## Calculating the outcome
i = 0
while i < 1:

    if operation == '+':
        number_1 = add(number_1, number_2)
        print('Answer is: ', round(number_1, 4))

    elif operation == '-':
        number_1 = subtract(number_1, number_2)
        print('Answer is: ', round(number_1, 4))

    elif operation == '*':
        number_1 = multiply(number_1, number_2)
        print('Answer is: ', round(number_1, 4).format)

    elif operation == '/':
        number_1 = divide(number_1, number_2)
        print('Answer is: ', round(number_1, 4))

    else:
        print("Invalid input")
 ## Asking for the second number

    try:
        operation, number_2 = input('''
        Starting at the previous outcome
        Please enter an operator and a number 
        Enter: ''').split()
    except ValueError:
        print('nee gap')


    number_2 = float(number_2)

    if operation == 'q':
        break
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1fuB.png)

Comment: You're testing `number_2` before you ever assign it.

Comment: Also, `while number_2 = None :` should be `while number_2 == None :`

Comment: @mozway `while number_2 is None` is a bit better

Answer (score 1):

You've written `continue` in the first `try` section, which means, if the condition is satisfied, it'll continue the loop again, and check for number_2 and if the input is correct, again it will continue the loop. So try deleting the `continue` statement, if the error is occured, it'll directly go to `except` section

Also, you've to write `==` to compare the values in `while number_2 == None`

And you've to define number_2 and operation before using it in while loop. It'll give you error that number_2 is not defined

---

```
result=0
while True:
    a=input("Enter operator and number= ")
    if len(a)>=2 and a[0] in ["+","-","*","/"]:
        h=int(a[1::])
        if a[0]=="+":
            result+=h
        elif a[0]=="-":
            result-=h
        elif a[0]=="*":
            result*=h
        elif a[0]=="/":
            result/=h
        else:
            print("choose only from +-/*")
    else:
        print("invalid input")
    ch=input("Enter more?")
    if ch=='n':
        break

print(f"The result is {result}")
```

Here, the user has to input both parameters as well as the number, I'm taking it as a string because you can traverse it later on and can seperate the operator and number. Initial result is 0. As the user puts the input, we'll traverse the string and seperate number and operator, (say "+9") operator will be `<input>[0]` and number will be `int(<input>[1::])`. Now we have seperated the numbers. Let's check for operator using if condition and calculate according. Hope this answer satisfies your aim, if not let me know your aim, I'll surely design a new one

Comment: Or replace `continue` with `break`.

Comment: I have deleted both 'continue' statements, but still it asks for input two times after the first time..

Comment: Perfection! I think break statement is not required, it'll directly go to except section but still, break works

Comment: Where is the second continue statement?

Comment: I have added a picture to illustrate what I mean. I ask for input the first time outside the loop and then I want the loop to continues calculate with the previous answers.

Comment: Wait, I had answered a similar question in which the aim was, the user himself has to put the operator as well as the number, the initial value will be 0 and as the user inputs the operations, python keeps calculating it and when the user says "n", to stop calculating, it gives the result. Remember, the initial value is 0. If you want that code, let me know, I'll post another answer

Comment: Yes please. I dont know if this is a normal question but if u can explain it to me via Skype or something I would be so thankful haha.

Comment: Sure, I'll write a new answer, check it out. I'll try to explain the whole code and please comment whether it satisfies your aim or not, if not, tell me your aim, I'll design a new one for you

Comment: So my aim is to filter out any ValueErrors and also any inputs that are no numbers

Comment: I copied the text of your other answer in to this one. You should only post multiple answers if they are so different that it doesn't make sense to have them in a single post. For most cases, though, [edit] your existing answer to add clarifications. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384666/843953

Comment: Ok, I'm not experienced of stackoverflow, it has not been more than a month till date